# Weird observation in JQuery / IFrames

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Here's the situation.

```
function scrollLog(line) { // Assume Firefox
    // alert("weird");
    frames['log'].find(line);
};
```

Here's a function I call when the document is ready.  The code as written does not always fire .  However, uncomment the alert line, and after the alert is fired, the find function always fires. Any ideas?

EDIT: Could this possibly be due to a load() issue where the timing of the loading of the iframe is not complete all the time? (These are pretty big log files)

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often adding an alert will do funky stuff when javascript tries to communicate with something else. I experienced this with flash, when putting alerts would leave time for the flash to load and it would work. Removing the alert would break everything.

Here I'd say since you put an alert it give time to the frame to load and therefore you're able to access it. When you don't have an alert, it might not be loaded completely. Tries to check if the frame is loaded before accessing it.

Comment: What's the syntax for checking if the frame is loaded?

Comment: You could do iframe.onload = function(){} I guess

Comment: There's nothing funky about alert.  DOM/resource dependent code *sometimes* works better when you pepper your code with alerts because it blocks execution until you dismiss it, which, of course, allows for more time to load the DOM/resource you are working with.

Comment: That's what I was saying, sorry if I wasn't clearer. When I say funky, it's because it makes everything really hard to figure out and debug when you're not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that the main document dom could be loaded before the iframe's document DOM is loaded.

Have you tried basing it on the frames element?

```
$(frames['log']).ready( function () {});
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking right after I posted -- gonna quickly try it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, marcgg's "onload" syntax turned out to work.